# Galvanic Cell Temperature Dependence

Tags: electrochemistry, redox

I'm currently studying the temperature dependence of the following cell: $\ce{Cu_{(s)} + 2Ag^{+}_{(aq)} <=> 2Ag_{(s)} + Cu^{2+}_{(aq)}}$ ($E^⦵ = \pu{+0.46 V}$)

Experimentally, I recorded the initial temperature of the cell at $\pu{273 K}$, before increasing the temperature of the cell and recording its potential each time. This nicely followed the equation:
$$E^⦵ = T\frac{\Delta S^⦵}{nF} - \frac{\Delta H^⦵}{nF}$$
Which apparently can be used to describe cell temperature dependence. It's worth noting that the activities of all species was 1.

---

The issue is that in retrospect, the entire experiment seemed kind of pointless, as it doesn't appear to actually tell me anything at all. Consider the following logic:

In a 'normal' equilibrium reaction, *e.g.* the Haber process, the reaction will proceed until it gradually reaches equilibrium, giving an equilibrium constant; let's call it $K_{1}$. Changing system temperature will shift the equilibrium until a new equilibrium is formed, with a new equilibrium constant $K_{2}$... And so on for each temperature change.

In a cell, this is not what happens. If we consider that $E^⦵$ is a 'guide' to equilibrium position, and assumed that the above *was* true, then changing temperature would've caused a new value of $E^⦵$ to equilibrate each time. However, we know it doesn't do this, as by definition equilibrium in a cell is when $E^⦵ = \pu{0 V}$. Therefore, this seems to me as though a cell will naturally reach equilibrium  with the same equilibrium constant at any temperature.

---

Thus, apart from giving me rather accurate, experimentally derived values for $\Delta H^⦵$ and $\Delta S^⦵$ (assuming that these parameters aren't temperature dependent, I know), what does the experiment actually tell me? I mean, the cell is predisposed to run to equilibrium and thus have an $E^⦵$ value of $\pu{0 V}$ regardless of temperature, so where does the temperature dependence come into it?

Furthermore, this makes it confusing to study how the reaction quotient (and equilibrium constant) varied with temperature:

- It's logical to extrapolate the graph and find the temperature at which equilibrium is apparently achieved; but as discussed, it doesn't work like that.
- It's also logical to calculate both parameters at each temperature (which appears to fit nicely as my calculations show that $\log K$ decreases with temperature, vice versa for $\log Q$) and finding the point where $\log K = \log Q$ would surely give me the temperature at equilibrium; but again, as discussed it doesn't work like that, mainly because 'equilibrium' results in $E^⦵ > 0$

So is there any simple way to determine how the reaction quotient changed with temperature?